# how to close ie8 tabs

Tags: delphi, winapi, internet-explorer-8

This code below is not closing a tab in Internet Explorer 8. If I post wm_close command to Wnd it closes Internet Explorer but I want to close the current tab not the entire 'ieframe'. Is FindWindowEX(Wnd , 0, 'Frame Tab', nil) supposed to retun a handle to ie frame? If yes why is it not closing the current tab in Internet Explorer?

```
var
   Wnd, WndChild : hwnd;
begin
   Wnd := FindWindow('IEFrame', nil);
   WndChild := FindWindowEX(Wnd, 0, 'Frame Tab', nil);
   postmessage(WndChild, wm_close, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is even possible.

Comment: @George: Well, in *theory* it should be possible, if IE8 is creating actual windows for the tabs, which seems likely. The trick is finding the right window handle, which may be very difficult indeed -- or not even possible, as you said. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed 1 layer, the tab itself, other than that, it was fine..

```
var
  Wnd, WndChild: THandle;
begin
  Wnd := FindWindow('IEFrame', nil); // Top most IE
  if Wnd > 0 then
  begin
    WndChild := FindWindowEx(Wnd, 0, 'Frame Tab', nil); // Tabs holder
    if WndChild > 0 then
    begin
      WndChild := FindWindowEX(WndChild, 0, 'TabWindowClass', nil); // top most tab
      if WndChild > 0 then
        if PostMessage(WndChild, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0) then
          ShowMessage('Close request succeeded...')
        else
          ShowMessage('Failed!');
    end
    else
      // not tabbed, close IE
        if PostMessage(Wnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0) then
          ShowMessage('Close request succeeded...')
        else
          ShowMessage('Failed!');
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('No IE');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  hie,
  hftab,
  htab : DWORD;
begin
  hie := FindWindow('IEFrame', nil);
  hftab := FindWindowEx(hie, 0, 'Frame Tab', nil);
  htab := FindWindowEX(hftab, 0, 'TabWindowClass', nil);
  PostMessage(htab, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
  CloseHandle(hie);
end;`
```

IE8 Window structure is shown in screenshot below

[alt text http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/6702/captureids.png](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/6702/captureids.png)

Comment: thanks for the reply
i have few confusions:
1.why did you use dword instead of hwnd.
2. is closehandle(htab) equvalent to htab := nil
3. is closehandle necessary, wont the handles be automaticaly closed once my program exits?

Comment: Very bad code example. 1) You should check the result of FindWindow[Ex]. 2) You do NOT close handles returned by the FindWindow[Ex].

Comment: Actually, this was to show an idea of how that should be done, leaving some space for thinking (error catching). Where you found about not closing handles (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500(VS.85).aspx says nothing of it)? And yes, closing handle of window received WM_CLOSE indeed generates exception (that's why I didn't closed it).

Comment: Help for FindWindow[Ex] says nothing about necessity to close handles. What you get from the FindWindow[Ex] is a globally visible handle; the call does not 'open' something for you so there's no need to close anything.

Comment: +1 for the screencap from Spy++, -1 for not removing `CloseHandle()` from your code even after you were (correctly) told it was wrong.

Comment: `CloseHandle` doesn't work with window handles. It only works with a certain class of kernel handles, such as process- or file-handles. A window handle is more like a global name. And you shouldn't simply close kernel handles either. Since that can lead to the handle being closed twice which means you get undefined behavior and crashes.